# MySQL Cluster Replication Configuration

Tags: mysql, replication, cluster-computing, database-replication

I am trying to setup replication with a single replication channel between two MySQL clusters. I have followed the documentation from mysql.com a couple of times, and can not seem to get it working properly.

The problem I'm having is that queries made to an SQL node that is not configured as the Master is not replicating any INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE queries for NDBCLUSTER tables, however when I INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE a row on the SQL node that is the master, it replicates to the other cluster fine.

I know that replication is setup because if I run a CREATE DATABASE query on any SQL Node in my Master cluster, it replicates fine to the Slave cluster. Likewise, if I run a CREATE TABLE query on any SQL node to create a NDBCLUSTER table in my new database, it too replicates to the Slave cluster fine.

The way I read the documentation and how I have understood cluster replication to work is that you could have 10 API nodes in your cluster, with one of those nodes configured for and dedicated to replication as the Master. So if an INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE query occurs on any of the 10 API nodes in the cluster, then the replication master and the NDB binlog will pick this up allowing slaves to then replicate. This does not seem to be working for me.

Is my understanding correct?

Here's how I've set things up:

All servers are VMs running 64-bit CentOS 6.2 and MySQL Cluster 7.2.8 x86_64.

**Cluster 1 (Master Cluster):**
1 x ndb_mgmd Management Node (Server 1A - IP: 10.14.64.10)
2 x mysqld API nodes (Servers 1B and 1C - IPs: 10.14.64.11 and 10.14.64.12)
2 x ndbd Data nodes (Servers 1D and 1E - IPs: 10.14.64.13 and 10.14.64.14)

**Cluster 2 (Slave Cluster):**
1 x ndb_mgmd Management Node (Server 2A - IP: 10.13.64.10)
2 x mysqld API nodes (Servers 2B and 2C - IPs: 10.13.64.11 and 10.13.64.12)
2 x ndbd Data nodes (Servers 2D and 2E - IPs: 10.13.64.13 and 10.13.64.14)

Here is a pretty picture to assist in explaining:
(had to include a link because this is my first post)

http://cpjon.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/mysql-cluster-replication.png

I have replication setup so that Server 1C is the Replication Master and Server 2C is the Replication Slave.

Here is the /etc/my.cnf file for Server 1C (being the MASTER):

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=10.14.64.10
log-bin
binlog-format=ROW
server-id=10

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=10.14.64.10
```

Here is the /etc/my.cnf file for Server 2C (being the SLAVE):

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=10.13.64.10
server-id=11

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=10.13.64.10
```

When I run the query **CREATE DATABASE test_db1;** on either SQL Server 1B or 1C, it is replicated instantly to Cluster 2, and I can see database **test_db1** on SQL Servers 2B and 2C.

When I run the following **CREATE TABLE** query:

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Name` char(35) NOT NULL default '',
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL default '',
  `District` char(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

on either SQL Server 1B or 1C, it is replicated instantly to Cluster 2, and I can see my newly created table **City** on SQL Servers 2B and 2C.

However, *here is the problem* - when I run the following query on **Server 1B**:

```
INSERT INTO City VALUES (1,'Melbourne','AUS','Victoria',4100000);
```

I can see the entry on all SQL nodes in Cluster 1 (ie. Servers 1B and 1C), but can not see the entry on any SQL nodes in Cluster 2 (ie. Server 2B and 2C).

If I run a similar query on **Server 1C**:

```
INSERT INTO City VALUES (2,'Sydney','AUS','New South Wales',4600000);
```

I can see the entry on all SQL nodes in Cluster 1 **AND** Cluster 2 - so on all four SQL nodes - which is what I expect.

I must be missing something really simple. I have tried blowing away these servers and starting again on numerous occations - and can't seem to get any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries on Server 1B going to my secondary cluster.

Any pointers or assistance would be greatly appreciated (and sorry for the long winded post)

Regards,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Enable binlog on 1B.

To enable it add to my.cfg:

```
log-bin=binlog
binlog-format=ROW
```